# how to deploy dynamic maps without deploying google maps?

Tags: maps

i want to embed maps in a project which includes developing a web portal for a city . The map should be dynamic and should help tourists in knowing various directions , bus routes , train routes , and other spots like nearest hospital or police station . But i dont want to implement google maps , as i dont think so i can do all that on a google map . So i am planning to create my own dynamic map of the particular city from the static maps of it . I want to know how feasible it is !

Comment: Not to discredit any answers, but to answer with a correction: You *can* do the above with Google maps. You can highlight routes, add your own points of interest to the maps, etc. But since your question is "how to... without google..." I won't submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/).

Answer (score 0):

And see [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) for free use map data

Answer (score 0):

As above - openlayers and openstreetmap data. You might also want to look at [TileDrawer](http://tiledrawer.com/)